# What is the simplest way to initialize an Array of N numbers following a simple pattern?

Tags: c#

Let's say the first N integers divisible by 3 starting with 9.

I'm sure there is some one line solution using lambdas, I just don't know it that area of the language well enough yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to be different (and to avoid using a where statement) you could also do:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => i * 3 + 9);
```

**Update** This also has the benefit of not running out of numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Using Linq:

```
int[] numbers =
    Enumerable.Range(9,10000)
    .Where(x => x % 3 == 0)
    .Take(20)
    .ToArray();
```

Also easily parallelizeable using PLinq if you need:

```
int[] numbers =
    Enumerable.Range(9,10000)
    .AsParallel()             //added this line
    .Where(x => x % 3 == 0)
    .Take(20)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const int __N = 100;
const int __start = 9;
const int __divisibleBy = 3;


var array = Enumerable.Range(__start, __N * __divisibleBy).Where(x => x % __divisibleBy == 0).Take(__N).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 10; // Take first 10 that meet criteria
int[] ia = Enumerable
              .Range(0,999)
              .Where(a => a % 3 == 0 && a.ToString()[0] == '9')
              .Take(n)
              .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to see how this solution stacks up to the above Linq solutions. The trick here is modifying the predicate using the fact that the set of `(q % m)` starting from `s` is `(s + (s % m) + m*n)` (where n represent's the nth value in the set). In our case `s=q`.

The only problem with this solution is that it has the side effect of making your implementation depend on the specific pattern you choose (and not all patterns have a suitable predicate). But it has the *advantage* of:

1. Always running in exactly n iterations
2. Never failing like the above proposed solutions (wrt to the limited `Range`).

Besides, no matter what pattern you choose, you will always need to modify the predicate, so you might as well make it mathematically efficient:

```
static int[] givemeN(int n)
{
    const int baseVal = 9;
    const int modVal = 3;

    int i = 0;
    return Array.ConvertAll<int, int>(
        new int[n],
        new Converter<int, int>(
            x => baseVal + (baseVal % modVal) + 
                ((i++) * modVal)
        ));
}
```

edit: I just want to illustrate how you could use this method with a `delegate` to improve code re-use:

```
static int[] givemeN(int n, Func<int, int> func)
{
    int i = 0;
    return Array.ConvertAll<int, int>(new int[n], new Converter<int, int>(a => func(i++)));
}
```

You can use it with `givemeN(5, i => 9 + 3 * i)`. Again note that I modified the predicate, but you can do this with most simple patterns too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is any good, I'm not a C# expert and I just whacked it out, but I think it's probably a canonical example of the use of `yield`.

```
internal IEnumerable Answer(N)
{
  int n=0;
  int i=9;
  while (true)
  {
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
      n++;
      yield return i;
    }

    if (n>=N) return;
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through 0 or 1 to N and add them by hand.  Or, you could just create your function f(int n), and in that function, you cache the results inside session or a global hashtable or dictionary.

Pseudocode, where ht is a global Hashtable or Dictionary (strongly recommend the later, because it is strongly typed.

```
public int f(int n)
{
  if(ht[n].containsValue)
    return ht[n];
  else
  {
    //do calculation
    ht[n] = result;
    return result;
   }
}
```

Just a side note.  If you do this type of functional programming all the time, you might want to check out F#, or maybe even Iron Ruby or Python.